# A Jewish slave in an Egyptian house?

Tags: passover, rashi, egypt, nissan

Rashi brings down the Mechilta and comments that an Egyptian in a Jewish house the night of the 15 of Nisan was killed by the Makkah and a Jew in an Egyptian house at the same time was spared, because the verse Shemot 12:13 states לא יהיה בכם נגף.

What protected the Jews of the Makkat Bechorot in their own houses?
An easy answer would be the blood of the Korban Pesach they put on the doorposts. But in that case, what protected an isolated Jew in an Egyptian house during the same plague?

Comment: I read somewhere that the blood on the doorpost did not protect Jews. It was symbolic. What protected Jews was G-d

Comment: @Turk Hill, any source please?

Comment: I cannot remember the source right now. But the idea is definitely correct, since objects, even if holy does not protect. Rabbi skin has an excellent essay on whether or not the Torah protects. He says that it does not protect in this sense. Only G-d protects (Maimonides).